# How do I easily access all subfolders and files within an nginx reverse proxy server?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm not sure if I can even describe what I want/my current problem because honestly, I don't know exactly what I am doing. currently I have arenu.com.br going to a nginx server reverse proxying to port 8080. Here's what I did on my server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have a simple node express hello.js file listening at port 8080 like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening at 8080'))
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

inside my 'public' folder there is an index.html page which is what you see when you go to the website.
The only way I found how to make other subdomains point to other static files is through the nginx settings like this:

```
server{
    location /snakegame/ { 
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/snakegame/index.html;
    }
}
```

Here I am accessing another index.html file located at /public/snakegame/index.html by proxying arenu.com.br/snakegame to it. This setup however, is not versatile at all and I have to manually add every single subfolder to the settings everytime, and multiple problems occur. One of the problems as an example is this:

While accessing directly my server at port 8080: http://142.93.144.178:8080/snakegame/index.html the javascript on that page works perfectly (use arrow keys to control snake). But when accessing the same file using this reverse proxy method, the javascript does not work: https://arenu.com.br/snakegame/ (you can even look at the console to see that it can't access the js file)

Is there a better way for nginx to access multiple subfolders and static content easily? What should I do?

Comment: Well… that’s proxying all requests to the index specifically, ignoring the requested path. This sounds Ike the simplest/commonest use of proxy pass, [the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) have a relevant example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same Kinda problem just a few days ago, there is little documentation about this as most people prefer to define their subfolders manually in the Nginx server config. In my case, I was using LXD containers and needed to pass a domain through the hypervisor to the LXD container. In order to do this I had to change the config for the Nginx hypervisor container (proxy_pass):

```
    location /snakegame/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0:8080/snakegame/;
            try_files $uri $uri/  @backend;
    }
    location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0:8080/snakegame/;
    }
```

I have changed the IP to match your requirments. I belive what happens is any request to the main index in your case index.html is forwarded but then the rest is sent to the Nginx proxy. the try_files and @backend seems to fix this. I'm not going to claim I know why :).

Comment: Why add try files usage here? It sounds like that’ll only work/do anything if coincidentally nginx has the same root as the express app

Comment: Like I said I'm not too sure exactly how this works, but I believe if a file can not be found as it queries the Nginx proxy it will also attempt to find the file/folder on the proxied Nginx site. I believe that is what try files is doing. However, I am not sure.

Comment: That is what try files does, my question is why is it in the answer - it is not relevant to the asked question, so it can be removed. See [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67727303/how-do-i-easily-access-all-subfolders-and-files-within-an-nginx-reverse-proxy-se/71805275?noredirect=1#comment126891867_67727303) for a reference (note also that `there is little documentation …` sounds like a misunderstanding).